# Can't install Azure SDK 2.7.1

Tags: azure, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015

When I try to install the Azure SDK 2.7.1, it says the the web development feature must be turned on. Does anyone know where it is or how it can be turned on. The dialog said use VS2015 help, but there is no reference for it.
Thanks up front ....

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you unselected the Web development tools when you installed VS.  Changing this is easy: in Control Panel, launch the VS installer from Programs and Features (it might say uninstall but that just fine).  You'll be able to select the Web development components.